# Possible values of symmetric functions evaluated on quaternions

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-rings, symmetric-polynomials, quaternion-algebras

$\DeclareMathOperator\sym{sym}$Let $i$, $j$, $k$ be the units of quaternions, in particular $i^2=j^2=k^2=-1$, $ijk=-1$.

We will use non commutative variables $x$, $y$, $z$. Define $\sym_{a,b,c}$ to be the  polynomial made of the sum of monomials which are all possible products of $a$ variables $x$, $b$ variables $y$ and $c$ variables $z$.

For example $\sym_{2,1,0}(i,j,k)=i^2 j+i j i+j i^2$.

Considering the symmetric definition of $\sym_{a,b,c}$ and the non commutativity of quaternions I would expect a lot of simplifications on $\sym_{a,b,c}(i,j,k)$, in fact $\sym_{a,0,0}(i,j,k)=i^a$, and $\sym_{1,1,1}(i,j,k)=0$ but $\sym_{2,2,0}(i,j,k)=i^2 j^2+j^2 i^2=2$.

Is there a simple formula to determine the value of  $\sym_{a,b,c}(i,j,k)$ in terms of $a$, $b$, $c$?

---

May/29/2019
By the way I introduced those functions we have:
$e^{(i+j+k)/\sqrt3}=\sum_n (\sqrt{3}^n/n!)\sum_{a,b,c} \sym_{a,b,c}(i,j,k) =(i+j+k)\sin(90)=i+j+k$.

Comment: These are not what are normally called "symmetric polynomials" (but I don't know a better term for them).

Comment: @SamHopkins Ok I edited it.

Comment: Note that the product of $a$ copies of $i$, $b$ copies of $j$ and $c$ copies of $k$, in any order, is determined up to sign by $a$, $b$ and $c$.  Since  the sign alternates with transpositions, you should be able to give a combinatorial argument to obtain the formula.

Comment: @Name displayed I think Sam Hopkins' point was that they're not what is usually called symmetric (they are polynomials)

Comment: In $\operatorname{sym}_{a, 0, 0}(i, j, k) = i^n$, $n$ and $a$ should be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Careful counting gives the following formula:
$$ \operatorname{sym}_{a,b,c}(i,j,k) = 
{\left\lfloor \frac{a}{2}\right\rfloor +\left\lfloor \frac{b}{2}\right\rfloor +\left\lfloor \frac{c}{2}\right\rfloor  \choose \left\lfloor \frac{a}{2}\right\rfloor ,\left\lfloor \frac{b}{2}\right\rfloor ,\left\lfloor \frac{c}{2}\right\rfloor }\cdot \delta(a,b,c) \cdot i^a j^b k^c $$
where
$$ \delta(a,b,c) = \left(1-(a\%2)\cdot(b\%2)-(b\%2)\cdot(c\%2)-(c\%2)\cdot(a\%2)+2(a\%2)(b\%2)(c\%2)\right) $$
is $0$ when at least two of $a$, $b$, $c$ are odd, and $1$ otherwise.
One might further evaluate using
$$ i^aj^bk^c = (-1)^{bc+\frac{c(c-1)}{2}+\left\lfloor \frac{a+c}{2}\right\rfloor +\left\lfloor \frac{b+c}{2}\right\rfloor }\cdot i^{(a+c)\%2}j^{(b+c)\%2}
$$
to actually get a multiple of one of the basis elements.